# How to add view above actionbar in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

According to new design of our android app i should add some view (video player) above android actionbar. The activity has actionbar by default. Is it possible to add my view above actionbar and how?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean horizontally above, or z-ordered above?

Comment: horizontally above actionbar (between app title and actionbar).

Comment: Could you show us an image of what you want ?

Comment: updated the question with image

Comment: You can't do that. ActionBar is always at the top. I would recommend to do as the next Google Play update : http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/nexusae0_store-4.9.13_thumb.jpg (top left images)

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong what you are looking for is something similar to the Google Plus Profile page look. For achieving that all you need to do is add the following in your Theme.

`<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>`

OR

`<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>`

When using actionbarcompat library

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html I think it won't allow to move action bar down

Comment: It wont allow. He added the screenshot later on. 
According to what screenshot has been shared, AFAIK you will have to implement your own actionbar.

Comment: overlaying is probably a good workaround but it's not adding view above itself so it's still workaround but not the solution

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to use a theme without the action bar and add your own custom view as a replacement. That way you can position as needed.

Comment: i've been thinking about it but it's not good in general. It means i have to implement fake actionbar myself

Comment: I would say it's probably possible to do it another way but most likely causes issues with older apis, if that is a concern. Just a suggestion on an approach that might work better for your needs.